# PHP strcmp not comparing properly

Tags: php, string, webserver

I have a simple login script written in php and when I run it is supposed to compare 2 password hashes from eachother. Here is the code im using;

```
$UUID = $_POST['UUID'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

// finds the same user where the uuid is the same as the one given in the post request
$query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UUID = '$UUID'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//gets the info
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Password = $row['UUIDPass']; // gets the hashed password from the server
    $salt = $row['salt']; // gets the salt from the server
}

// hashes the given password with the salt from the MYSQL server
$passcheck = hash("sha256", $pass . $salt);

// checks if the hashed password above is the same as the hash in the server
if (strcmp($Password, $passcheck))
{
    echo "Correct!";
}
else
{
    echo "Something went wrong!";
}
```

So what I'm doing here is, i'm comparing a password given by the user by the one in the server. What is wrong?

Comment: try with trim() if (strcmp(trim($Password), trim($passcheck))) or try to echo your both result are same

Comment: Please read the documentation for `strcmp`. It **returns `0` on success.**

Comment: @RakeshSharma trim() method did not work and I don't want to be echoing my users hashes

Comment: @deceze so I would try something like if(strcmp("one", "one") == 0) ?

Comment: @deceze should have posted it as an answer because that is what worked for me thank you

Comment: @dan14941, Hanky provided a good example and a reference, his answer is worthwhile to others in the future if deceze does not give an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for you

```
<?php

    if(strcmp("Hello","Hello"))
    {
      echo "Match";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "No Match";
    }
?>
```

Says `No Match` because your check was incorrect because the return value on success was `0`, you have to use

```
if(strcmp("Hello","Hello")==0)
```

It can also be confirmed from the manual itself

**[strcmp](http://php.net/strcmp)**

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: It is worth noting that for comparing hashed passwords the new [`hash_equals()`](http://php.net/hash_equals) function should be used, or at least considered (perhaps using `function_exists()`). More information can be found in [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/timing_attack).

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you use the same hash for your encryption.
also you have to use echo in every stage. strcmp() function works well in php.